# помогите сократить код в пайтон

Tags: python, tkinter

```
def cbtn_1():
    screened.append('1')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_2():
    screened.append('2')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_3():
    screened.append('3')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_4():
    screened.append('4')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_5():
    screened.append('5')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_6():
    screened.append('6')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_7():
    screened.append('7')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_8():
    screened.append('8')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
def cbtn_9():
    screened.append('9')
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
```

как сократить этот фрагмент кода с помощью цикла for?

Comment: Почему такое странное ограничение?

Comment: ограничений нет, просто предположил что через for сделать можно

Comment: А в чём сложность? Элементарно же. Или вообще питон не знаете?

Answer (score 1):

А так нельзя было:

```
def cbtn(num: int):
    screened.append(str(num))
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
```

И дальше хоть циклом, хотя вручную) Или так:

```
def cbtn(nums: list):
    screened.extend(nums)
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
```

Answer (score -1):

как вариант через for:

```py
for i in range(1, 10):
    screened.append(i)
    screenedreen["text"] = int_float(''.join(screened))
```

А вообще все очень зависит от реализации остального кода...

Comment: Это совсем не то. У автора 9 разных функций, а здесь просто все делается 8 (а не 9!) раз.

Comment: Да даже рядом на одно и то же. У автора 9 кнопок, при нажатии на одну из них выполняются две строчки кода -  добавляется одна цифра куда-то там. А в вашем коде что происходит?

Comment: Окей, замените "кнопки" на функции. Что изменилось?

Comment: Кто это сказал? Если мне нужно вызвать функцию cbtn_1(), то что я должен сделать с вашим кодом?

Comment: Есть мнение, что вы совершенно не поняли вопрос и даже не желаете понять, в чем ваша ошибка. Ну или не хочется признать, что не так понял. В этом ничего позорного нет, но многим западло, типа если признал, то лох.

Comment: Возможно вопрос мной не понят от слова совсем с этим не спорю...  но все же слишком много "а если..."

Comment: Да нет тут никаких если. Повторю вопрос - мне нужно вызвать функцию cbtn_1() из оригинального кода. Что мне в этом случае делать с вашим циклом?

Comment: @Эникейщик Вам возможно и надо это как раз это и есть "если" то есть та часть которая додумана...  а надо ли автору? Укажите где это указано в вопросе? то есть давайте не придумывать коня в вакууме а конструктивно где говорится в вопросе что надо так?

Comment: "Что надо так" это как?

Comment: @Эникейщик что должна вызываться отдельная функция... про цикл я например могу привести выдержку...  и если Вы обратите внимание в ответе есть упоминание про реализацию остального кода... так намек...  P.S. если честно надоело. предлагаю подчистить флуд и пусть решает автор он то как раз таки знает точно.

Comment: Т.е. вы думаете, что автор сделал 9 функций просто так, из любви к искусству, не имея в виду вызывать их по отдельности? И после этого обвиняете меня в додумывании?  если бы вы удосужились почитать комментарии под вопросом, то поняли бы кое- что, почему там упоминается цикл... Так намёк...

Comment: Кстати, у вопроса есть метка tkinter. Функции называются cbtn. Это к вопросу о кнопках. Ну так, намёк.

Comment: @Эникейщик  да/нет  все может быть...  Вы этого не знаете как и я..  и повторюсь P.S. если честно надоело. предлагаю подчистить флуд и пусть решает автор он то как раз таки знает точно.